# Error: Xdebug + Windows 10 + PhpStorm + Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, phpstorm, xdebug, docker-machine

I try to configure xdebug on my Windows machine, however I catch an error. 
Its Xdebug log:

```
[7] Log opened at 2020-04-23 15:57:27
[7] I: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9000.
[7] W: Creating socket for ‘host.docker.internal:9000’, getaddrinfo: Invalid argument.
[7] E: Could not connect to client. :-(
[7] Log closed at 2020-04-23 15:57:27
```

How I set up it:

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: docker/php-fpm
    volumes:
      - //c/Users/kam2r/sites/XDEBUG:/var/www
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_host=host.docker.internal remote_enable=1 remote_log=/var/www/xdebug.log"
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=Docker"
  nginx:
    build:
      context: docker/nginx
    volumes:
      - //c/Users/kam2r/sites/XDEBUG:/var/www
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "9000:9000"
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
```

I launch docker

```
$ docker-compose up -d --build
```

In PhpStorm I added docker server [image: server]

Added Interpreter:

[image]

After I validate debugger

[image: debugger]

Added PHP server
[image: phpserver]

Help please. Need your help!

Comment: Try with Xdebug ports to be 9001 (in both php.ini/xdebug config as well as PhpStorm (PHP Debug Xdebug section)) P.S. I'm not sure if you actually need this `- "9000:9000"` line in your docker-compose.yml file (from what I know how it works such line should prevent Xdebug from connecting to IDE...).

Comment: Did not help. https://skr.sh/s1sQJluEnBL

Comment: 1) Maybe some docker misconfiguration? As that host name should be available on Docker for Windows... 2) In such case try locating real IP address of your host machine (as seen from inside the Docker container) and use the actual IP instead (inconvenient for sure). E.g. something similar to this:https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264#issuecomment-385698947 3) Unlikely to be Windows Firewall (or antivirus software) based on the "getaddrinfo: Invalid argument" part...

Comment: Tried:
https://skr.sh/s1snYu4AOfo
Result:
https://skr.sh/s1sjjToO42M

Comment: Maybe it's firewall in your Docker then.... I do not know. But just in case: Xdebug is the one that connects to IDE. So 1) PhpStorm must be listening on Xdebug port on your Windows (use "phone handle" icon so it starts listening and check using `netstat` or alike that it's PhpStorm) 2) Xdebug then must connect from your container back to the docker host OS (Windows) where IDE is listening on that port. In general: try another (any) docker image where you can have SSH and try to connect to IDE from there using `telnet` or similar tool. That's to confirm that it;'s not firewall / network config.

Comment: You may also check https://www.pascallandau.com/blog/setup-phpstorm-with-xdebug-on-docker/ or similar tutorials (that is more suitable for your setup/environment) -- maybe you will see any difference in docker config or whatnot. Sadly I don't have any more concrete/better ideas right now.